# How to get id in array with search?

Tags: php, arrays

We have lists of categories (ID and Category Name) in variable $categories. However, since the category names are often ambiguous, we have another variables mapping variations of the category name to its original category name in $mapped_categories. For example, category name “Pancakes” mapped to original category name “Pancakes / Waffles / Crepes”, therefore have category ID of 133.

Source http://pastebin.com/yWPh4LkW

```
Example :
foreach($input_categories as $input_category)
{
   if(in_array($input_category, $categories))
            echo array_search($input_category, $categories).'<br/>';
}
```

$mapped_categories can not be read, Help me to get it.

Comment: $mapped_categories can not be read - what does it mean?

Comment: Source http://pastebin.com/yWPh4LkW

Answer (score 2):

I think you need intersection

```
var_dump(array_intersect($input_categories, $categories));
```

However, I don't know what $mapped_categories are because it is not clear from your question.

Other possible solution what you may look for is:

```
$intersected = array_intersect($input_categories, array_keys($mapped_categories));
$found = [];
foreach ($intersected as $el) {
   $found[] = array_search($mapped_categories[$el], $categories);
}
```

It will return keys of found categories based on mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You problem statement is not clear but I am taking a guess.

If an element from your input_categories, matches one of the categories then you return its `index`, otherwise you check the `$mapped_categories` for its mappedCatgory and then search the `$input_categories` and return the `index`(id)

So your code should be something like :

```
foreach($input_categories as $input_category) {
    if(in_array($input_category, $categories)) {
                echo array_search($input_category, $categories).'<br/>';
    } else if (!empty($mapped_categories[$input_category])) {
         $mappedCategory = $mapped_categories[$input_category];
         if(in_array($mappedCategory, $categories)) {
                echo array_search($mappedCategory, $categories).'<br/>';
         }
    } else {
       echo 'Not Found';
    }
}
```